# RSA Hastad's broadcast attack with large numbers

Tags: rsa, attack, visual-cryptography

I understand the theory behind Hastad's broadcast attack.

Namely if we have three encrypted messages with the exponent e=3:

```
c1 = m1 mod n1,
c2 = m2 mod n2,
c3 = m3 mod n3
```

Then we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find

```
c = c1 mod n1,
c = c2 mod n2,
c = c3 mod n3,
c = m^3 mod n1*n2*n3
```

and since n1 * n2 * n3 is too large, we simply have c = m^3

I only find explanations for smaller numbers but how are you supposed to find the solution for very large numbers such as

```
16833444999714344947074933154092703072048227929941882928373643621000348494347
```

?

Comment: Are you asking about how to compute a cube root (over the integers)?

Comment: Notice that in the question, $c_i=m_i\bmod n_i$ but $c\equiv c_i\pmod{n_i}$, and the difference in notation is essential: $c\ne c_i\bmod n_i$. Python works fine with large numbers. Should everything else be unobtainium, good old bisection will compute cube root.